# c++/c# app to connect to linux server

Tags: c#, c++, linux

I am planning to do an App either in c++/C# (through Visual Studio) in Windows 7.

OK what this app does is it will accept input through studio elements like text box or buttons ..then it should create an command based on input and run these command on the Linux server.

E.g : One simple example is to restart a certain process on a Linux machine

Now to proceed to my problem:

How do I connect my App to Linux machine?
I don't want to install any third party application as i am not allowed to do so.

If possible please list  me the different ways i can do this

Comment: No..in simple terms what i am asking is "from c# application on windows can i connect to a linux machine,so that i can execute commands on that machine."

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, to solve this you can implemente WebService.
But when you said :

> I dont want to install any third party application as i am not allowed
>   to do so

I'm afraid you can not setup WebService on Linux server ?

Other possibility, use SSH if already install on linux server (some chance that is) and you probably could find a .Net lib to make SSH

This link will help [.Net class to execute remotely on Linux over SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312010/net-class-to-execute-remotely-on-linux-over-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this. I am already familiar with this scenario. I have several application setup working this way. The only option that will allow you to do this without any 3rd party application is using SSH protocol.

The SSH protocol is the well known and most power full tool of linux sysadmins. You can execute any command over it on a linux box from any part of the world or any piece of shit which can run an SSH client. Ask me on comment if you need more info on this.

**EDIT**

One example, if you want to restart certain process.. You can pass the command over SSH as below.

```
ssh user@server_ip '/etc/init.d/httpd restart"
```

The above will restart the HTTPD(Apache) service.

**Some libraries you can use in .NET**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11966/sharpSsh-A-Secure-Shell-SSH-library-for-NET

https://sshnet.codeplex.com/

I have not used above libraries in .Net, Instead I have done several things using linux box with python and bash.

Comment: ya please tell me more..But not only SSH if any other methods are available.I read that you can do that using telnet,socket programming etc

Comment: yes but socket programming will give you too much of work and will need you to develop another program which will run on Linux machine (if you do like a client server process). But it is very simple to use SSH and SSH server is already installed in almost every Linux box except few cases.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do?are you suggesting i do that using Putty?

Comment: Nope. Do not use putty which is not your requirements. You can use a library which support SSH protocol and execute your command through that, See the above edit. It is just one line if you want to restart your webserver.

Comment: Thanks.but the thing is i cant use any libraries .Without any libraries is it not possible?

Comment: The libraries you will use is .Net library, that is part of the application you are building. If you can't use any library, you have to code the library yourselves.